# Reduce Spark RDD to return multiple values

Tags: apache-spark, reduce

I have the following RDD containing sets of items which I would like to group by item similarity (Items in the same set are considered similar. Similarity is transitive and all the items in sets which have atleast one common item are also considered similar)

Input RDD:

```
Set(w1, w2)
Set(w1, w2, w3, w4)
Set(w5, w2, w6)
Set(w7, w8, w9)
Set(w10, w5, w8) --> All the first 5 set elements are similar as each of the sets have atleast one common item
Set(w11, w12, w13)
```

I would like the above RDD to be reduced to

```
Set(w1, w2, w3, w4, w5, w6, w7, w8, w9, w10)
Set(w11, w12, w13)
```

Any suggestions on how I could do this ? I am unable to do something like below where I could ignore reducing two sets if they don't contain any common elements:

```
data.reduce((a,b) => if (a.intersect(b).size > 0) a ++ b ***else (a,b)***)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `reduce` algorithm are actually incorrect. For example, what if one set cannot be merge with the next set, but can still be merged with a different set in the collect.

There're probably better ways, but I think up a solution to this by converting it to a graph problem and use Graphx.

```
val data = Array(Set("w1", "w2", "w3"), Set("w5", "w6"), Set("w7"), Set("w2", "w3", "w4"))
val setRdd = sc.parallelize(data).cache

// Generate an unique id for each item to use as vertex's id in the graph
val itemToId = setRdd.flatMap(_.toSeq).distinct.zipWithUniqueId.cache
val idToItem = itemToId.map { case (item, itemId) => (itemId, item) }

// Convert to a RDD of set of itemId
val newSetRdd = setRdd.zipWithUniqueId
  .flatMap { case (sets, setId) =>
    sets.map { item => (item, setId) }
  }.join(itemToId).values.groupByKey().values

// Create an RDD containing edges of the graph
val edgeRdd = newSetRdd.flatMap { set =>
    val seq = set.toSeq
    val head = seq.head
    // Add an edge from the first item to each item in a set, 
    // including itself
    seq.map { item => Edge[Long](head, item)}
  }

val graph = Graph.fromEdges(edgeRdd, Nil)

// Run connected component algorithm to check which items are similar.
// Items in the same component are similar
val verticesRDD = graph.connectedComponents().vertices

verticesRDD.join(idToItem).values.groupByKey.values.collect.foreach(println)
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks. Never explored Spark's Graphx library and it's time I do it.